# Hong-Ou-Mandel (HOM) effect in Bohm interpretation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-optics, quantum-interpretations

Can someone answer how is [Hong-Ou-Mandel (HOM) effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hong%E2%80%93Ou%E2%80%93Mandel_effect) treated in Bohm interpretation? I looked on the net but couldnt find anything.

Comment: It is probably captured by the pilot wave which if I recall correctly is basically the wavefunction. This would reduce the question down to how is the Hong-Ou-Mandel effect treated in field theories, then both the physical degrees of freedom will both choose the same path since this is all that is allowed by the pilot wave.

Comment: But I'd have to do the maths to be certain

Comment: @NAMcMahon The waves coming from different in-ports of MZI (when there is a single photon) when the phase lag is chosen appropriately can interfere positively and add in just one out-port. The other must be empty. Always by that phase lag. The experiment shows 50/50 probability for both out-ports. This in QM, EM all the same.